# Wasserstein distance between $X$ and $X+N$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, signal-processing

Is there a way to calculate the Wasserstein distance (or any other distance) between the distribution of a random variable $X \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and the distribution of $X+N$ where $N \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2\mathbb{I}_d)$ is small perturbation along the dimensions ?